# How to use an array of data and a for loop to instantiate objects?

Tags: javascript, class, loops

**I have two arrays one with data**

```
var elements = [["1","a",1],["2","b",2],["3","c",3],["4","d",4],["5","e",5]];
```

**And another one with names of the objects which I want to create using data above.**

```
var names =["a1","a2","a3","a4","a5"];
```

**This is the prototype class**

```
var Video = function(title,uploader,seconds){
this.title = title;
this.uploader = uploader;
this.seconds = seconds;
}
```

I expect to get:

a1 which will have values: title:"1",uploader:"a",seconds:1

a2 with values: title:"2",uploader:"b",seconds:2

Same with rest.

Or is maybe is there other way to complete task below ?

**Use an array of data and a for loop to instantiate 5 Video objects.**

Comment: Which task ? This question is not clear to me...

Comment: What do you mean by "names of objects"? Objects don't  have names. They can be held in a variable, or an array, or another object...

Comment: I need to use an array of data and for loop to create 5 class instance.

Comment: What's an instant object?

Comment: names of objects... array 'names' is holding strings, which i want to use to create new class instance.

Comment: 5 instances ? from what I see you're providing data for 3 instances. Please add an output example of what you're expecting.

Comment: "*strings, which i want to use to create new class instance*" - use how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function Video(title, uploader, seconds) {
    this.title = title;
    this.uploader = uploader;
    this.seconds = seconds;
}

var elements = [["1","a",1],["2","b",2],["3","c",3],["4","d",4],["5","e",5]];

var names =["a1","a2","a3","a4","a5"];

// create instances
var videos = elements.map(data => new Video(...data));

// add them to hashmap
var result = names.reduce((acc, current, index) => {
    acc[current] = videos[index];
    return acc;
  }, {});

console.log(result);
```